# How to convert a nested list to a single list?

Tags: r, list, nested, lapply

Consider the following nested list:

```
vars <- c("A", "B")
lapply(1:2, function(x) combn(vars, x, simplify=FALSE))

[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] "A"

[[1]][[2]]
[1] "B"

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] "A" "B"
```

I want to convert the results (maybe by using a different function other than *lapply*) to the following:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A"

[[2]]
[1] "B"

[[3]]
[1] "A" "B"
```

Comment: @bn4t Yes. I have simplified my question to learn how the approach by other people is.

Comment: Soheil, please show the code you used to produce your current expected output, not just the code to generate sample data.

Comment: Or `purrr::flatten`

Comment: @r2evans That is the desired output. I want to know how to produce that result.

Comment: @MrFlick, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you just want to remove one level of nesting. You can do that with `unlist(..., recursive=FALSE)`

```
vars <- c("A", "B")
x <- lapply(1:2, function(x) combn(vars, x, simplify=FALSE))
unlist(x, recursive=FALSE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "A"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "B"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "A" "B"
```